# Java basic arithmetic and data type

Tags: java, math

Silly question but can't find the answer.

```
    double divider = 1000;

    List<Long> listLong = new ArrayList<>();
    listLong.add(1500L);
    listLong.add(8000L);

    for (Long val : listLong)
    {
        System.out.println((val/ divider));
    }
```

Gives me

```
1.5
8.0
```

and I want

```
1.5
8
```

`distance` and `distance2` are **Long** and can't be changed. 
`divider` has to be the same thing for both cases.

**ANWSER:**

**Thanks to  KevinO**

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    for (Long val : listLong)
    {
        System.out.println(df.format(val/ divider));
    }
```

Comment: You will need to format the output.

Comment: If you can't do any casting e.g. `System.out.println(distance2 / (int) divider)`, then you will have to do formatted output as @KevinO said.

Comment: @KevinO Thanks I guess it's the best thing to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `DecimalFormat`  like this:

```
  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.#");
  System.out.println(df.format(distance2 / divider));
```

Comment: I've updated the question to give you a better example

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DecimalFormat` to accomplish what you need. Going off of your updated question:

```
    double divider = 1000;

    List<Long> listLong = new ArrayList<>();
    listLong.add(1500L);
    listLong.add(8000L);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.#");

    for (Long val : listLong) {
        System.out.println(df.format(val / divider));
    }
```

Produces:

```
run:
1.5
8
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's the way to do it indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because one of the two parameters are of type `double`.

You can simply achieve what you are trying to achieve by adding a cast to integer by doing: `System.out.println((int) (distance2 / divider));`

Also, you should use primitives as it requires only a fraction of the memory. Replace `Long` with `long`.

Here is the corrected code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{
    List<Long> listLong = new ArrayList<>();
    listLong.add(1500L);
    listLong.add(8000L);
    double divider = 1000;

    for (long val : listLong)
    {
        int calc = (int)(val/divider);
        if((val/divider - calc) == 0) {
            System.out.println(calc);
        } else {
            System.out.println(val/divider);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1.5
8
```

Comment: I've updated the question to give you a better example

Comment: Thanks for you answer, really :) it works indeed but it's not the best way to do it. Reformatting the output is the best thing to do as KevinO suggested

Answer (score 0):

use DecimalFormat

what works for me:

public class NewClass {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DecimalFormat dcf= new DecimalFormat("#.#");
    Long distance = 1500L;
    Long distance2 = 8000L;
    double divider = 1000;

    System.out.println(dcf.format(distance / divider));
    System.out.println(dcf.format(distance2 / divider));
}
```

}


    output

```
1.5
8
```